# How to include class from another file into your main file

Tags: java, c++, compilation, include

I have two files : **JavaAssignment1.java** && **KeyBoard.java**

[image]

In **Keyboard.java** , there is a class called Keyboard

In C++ , it would be `#include "foobar.h"`

I have tried `import Keyboard.java` but it doesnt work , i have the following error :

```
package Keyboard doesnt exist
```

How do i include the Keyboard class in my JavaAssignment1.java so that i can use the KeyBoard class . ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in both classes you have no `package` declaration at the top or it is `package javaassignment1;` then you do not need to import anything. They have the same class path.

Comment: Given that they aren't in the default package, they wouldn't compile if they didn't have a package statement.

Comment: If that folder is set as the root compilation folder than they will not need the package because it will be the default. It could be either or, but I do agree since they are using an IDE it most likely has the package statement there already for them.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a package you do something like
    import packageName.*;
If you import particular class from package:
    import packageName.particularClassName;

If classes are in same packages you don't have to do imports.

Also please read on access modifiers and access levels.